# Which PHP version is used by Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi I am doing with Laravel 5.0. Its all fine but when I deploy my application to server its get partly dysfunctional (e.g. return redirect('action'); is giving error) on production server but working fine on localhost. On my local environment I have PHP 5.6.3 and on production its PHP 5.4.10. Can anybody tell me with which version of PHP Laravel 5.0 is compatible ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: return redirect('action'); and ajax calls are giving 500 error.
Meanwhile its working fine on localhost

Comment: `500` Error resembles the error in code. Can you check the error.log or see the error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.0 requires `PHP >= 5.4`

Also You should have enabled

```
Mcrypt PHP Extension
OpenSSL PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
```

Read more about the [Laravel 5.0 Server Requirements](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements)

Comment: I have checked, the production server has all these components installed.

Comment: then the issue is on coding.. You need to check that first

Comment: No, there's no syntax error and its working fine at localhost

Comment: can you say what error you getting with 500 error ?

Comment: Unable to serve this request, Site temporarily unavailable.
This error is at "return redirect('action')"

Comment: are you using it in sub domain or using.htaccess ?

Comment: and is the `action` function exist with appropriate http request ?

Comment: yes with appropriate http request and using .htaccess

Comment: Can u try in the request direct in browser or postman client ??

Comment: It's giving the same error while trying request directly in browser

Comment: So, the problem is in the server that you hosted.. !!

Comment: If i see the error in direct i may find the solution to fix it